# Python kivy entry point inflateRest2 could not be located libpng16-16.dll

Tags: python, dll, kivy

Installed Kivy as non-admin user. 
When I run a basic hello World I get "Python.exe Entry Point not found"  with these details:

> The procedure entry point inflateRest2 could not be located in the dll ....\python2.7\shared\sdl2\bin\libpng16-16.dll".[image: kivy_1]

When I hit okay then nothing loads.

After googling I added  these 2 statements:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'pil,sdl2'
```

and now when I run this it still shows the entry point error but shows the output as seen here: [image: Kivy_2]

How to fix the entry point issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I followed the installation instructions from here https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: My Win10 is 64bit and Py3.6 is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to find another dll

```py
import ctypes.util
ctypes.util.find_library("zlib1.dll")
```

> So i found the cause. Intel brings in their own zlib1.dll in C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\ and they add this directory to PATH. So whenever an app linked against zlib tries to execute without C:\msys64\mingw64\bin in PATH, it tries to load this different version of zlib, that doesn't contain the method. The real solution would be to poke into Intel and tell them to stop doing stupid things like plaguing system-wide PATH with their own things, but whatever. Just copy your mingw64 zlib1.dll into your app directory and call it a day.

https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/813

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Environment Variables **PATH** ,remove other python path.
2. My operation system is Windows10. copy **zlib1.dll** from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 to C:\Windows\System32 .
3. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem I went to the directory and found that the file was having an unequal name to the file name shown in the prompt thus try changing the name of the file in its directory.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the file size of `zlib1.dll` in `C:\Users\[user]\Anaconda3\share\sdl2\bin\` did not match the file size of the DLL with the same name in the `System32` folder. I simply moved the DLL file to `System32` and replaced the older file.